# Form contact in resposnive, how to change look

Tags: html, css, forms

How can I set the form elements like on the screen?

I would like to change the look of form contact.
Right now it's something like this[image]

And I want to get something like this [image]

Here's my code

HTML

```
<section class="contact">
        <h4 class="contact__title">Kontakt</h4>
        <div class="contact__box">
            <article class="contact__main">
                <p>iGroup</p>
                <p>ul. Wyspiańskiego 16</p>
                <p>05-091 Ząbki</p>

                <p><a href="tel:22 423-71-54"><span>Telefon:</span> 22 423-71-54</a></p>
                <p><a href="tel:22 864-09-84"><span>Telefon / fax:</span> 22 864-09-84</a></p>
                <p>
                    <a href="mailto:kontakt@parowe.com.pl"></a><span>E-mail:</span> kontakt@parowe.com.pl</p>

            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="contact__wrap">
            <form>

                <input name="name" placeholder="Imię">

                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Adres e-mail">

                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Treść wiadomości"></textarea>

                <input id="submit" class="contact__wrap--submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Wyślij">

            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

SCSS

```
.contact {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(10,198,162) 0%,rgb(0,160,175) 100%);

    &__title {
        font-family: $font;
        font-weight: 900;
        @include font-size(35px);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        padding-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    &__main {
        width: 220px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;

        p:nth-child(1) {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 500;
            @include font-size(25px);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 20px;
            @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
                text-align: left;
            }
        }

        p:nth-child(2) {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 300;
            @include font-size(25px);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            text-align: center;
            @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
                text-align: left;
            }
        }

        p:nth-child(3) {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 300;
            @include font-size(25px);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            text-align: center;
            @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
                text-align: left;
            }
        }

        p:nth-child(4) {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 500;
            @include font-size(25px);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 20px;
            @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
                text-align: left;
            }

            span {
                font-weight: 700;
                @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
                    text-align: left;
                }
            }
        }

        p:nth-child(5) {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 500;
            @include font-size(25px);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 5px;
            @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
                text-align: left;
            }

            span {
                font-weight: 700;
                @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
                    text-align: left;
                }
            }
        }

        p:nth-child(6) {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 500;
            @include font-size(25px);
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 25px;

            span {
                font-weight: 700;
            }
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
        }
    }

    &__box {
        @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {
            width: 300px;
        }
    }

    &__wrap {
        width: 240px;
        height: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 20px;

        ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: rgb(13,13,13);
            padding-left: 5px;
            @include font-size(30px);
        }

        :-moz-placeholder {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: rgb(13,13,13);
            padding-left: 5px;
            @include font-size(30px);
        }

        ::-moz-placeholder {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: rgb(13,13,13);
            padding-left: 5px;
            @include font-size(30px);
        }

        :-ms-input-placeholder {
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: rgb(13,13,13);
            padding-left: 5px;
            @include font-size(30px);
        }

        &--submit {
            width: 240px;
            height: 40px;
            margin: 20px auto 0;
            font-family: $font;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: rgb(13,13,13);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            @include font-size(30px);
            background: rgb(255,255,255);
            text-decoration: none;
            border: 0;
        }

        form {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            @media only screen and (min-width: $break-medium) {}

            input {
                border: none;
                margin-top: 5px;
                height: 40px;
                font-family: $font;
                font-weight: 900;
                color: rgb(13,13,13);
                @include font-size(30px);
            }

            textarea {
                resize: none;
                margin-top: 5px;
                height: 190px;
                font-family: $font;
                font-weight: 900;
                color: rgb(13,13,13);
                @include font-size(30px);
                padding-top: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWmaKX)

Comment: Where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: Hint: Make good use of the css property `float:left`

Comment: I tried with float etc, but it doesn't work well.

Comment: Daniel, look at the demo.

Answer (score 3):

Just use floating (float: left/right) or flexbox.

You will also need to change your HTML little bit. All floated elements should have some wrapper.

Here is a quick edit: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLWpYz

Btw. new mixin added:

```
@mixin clearfix() {
    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }
    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

The same way you can float the inputs. 1st: make a wrapper for them, set the cleaner for the wrapper, 2nd: float the childs.

I has not tested the responsive... but it will be ease to set some breakpoint to stop floating on smaller devices.

But the SCSS is quite rubbish and could be written much more easier and cleaner :-)

Answer (score 0):

Floating is now bad practice and is no longer necessary. Use flexbox!

Comment: "Bad practice"? Are you joking? It's not "bad practice", and if you're forced to support older browsers, flex-box is not an option. By all means, I'm all for using flex-box, but calling floats "bad practice" is a both undocumented and wrong.

Comment: Using float as a layout tool is bad practice. If the intention is to float an image and have the text wrap around it, have at it. But using it as a method to lay out your page is not the intention of the property. Taking it out of the document flow and having to clear is unnecessary. Flexbox is available in IE10+ (with prefixes), and IE10- is officially unsupported by Microsoft, and represents a miniscule portion of the marketshare.

Comment: Please provide some resources for this statement. Floats are perfectly valid for alignment, for instance inside a `<div>` where you want two (or more) dynamic content position on respectively the left and right. There is no reason to use flex for such a purpose. While the OPs question might very well benefit from using flex, I'm still not on board with the "bad practice", statement, so again, please provide some external information / discussions, especially from either w3g or similar authorities.

Comment: Your argument is equivalent to saying "It's fine to use tables for layout" the way we did in 1995. Sure - I guess, technically it's fine. But that's not what tables were designed for, and there are better, more flexible methods to do what tables used to. Sure - I guess floats are fine. But setting up page layout isn't what float was intended to do. It's why flexbox was developed, and why grid is being developed.

Comment: I didn't use tables for layout, even in 95. Sorry to say, but currently your argument is "this is my opinion, and I'll stick with it".

Comment: CSS came out in 1996, so I'm not sure what sorcery you were using prior to that. But you're right - it is my opinion that it's asinine to ask someone to build a house and not use power tools. Flexbox is the better tool for the job, and it's silly to create more for yourself by using an inferior layout tool. When grid has full browser support, I'll say the same thing about using flexbox as a layout tool. Flexbox will still be functional in terms of spacing items out, but it won't be the right tool for laying out your page. Until grid is ready, flexbox is the best method to do what OP is asking.